# Change dynamically only color of a Button that has a drawable in xml

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have buttons in my app that have a drawable in background:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/til"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
```

The drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="30dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />
```

If I do this:

```
loginButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getBgColor()));
```

Not only the color, but the entire shape of the button is changed, so no rounded corners, etc. How can I change only the color of the background, keeping the rest of things of my drawable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.blue));
```